# Add file path to message if regex matches

Tags: python, windows

I have the following Python script (excerpt below) which reads all log files under the E:\Data\Production directory and looks for certain regex matches.

```
errors, tr, warnings = [], [], []

rootdir = 'E:\\Data\\Production'

for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)
            with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    for match in re.finditer(r'.*' + daysdate + '(?!.*[->OK].*).*[Ee]rror.*', line):
                        errors.append(match.group(0))
                    for match in re.finditer(r'.*' + daysdate + '.*(?!.*deployed)(?!.*complete.*)(?!.*There are no.*)(?!.*disabled.*).*TR\d{4}.*', line):
                        warnings.append(match.group(0))
                    for match in re.finditer(r'.*' + daysdate + '.*(?!.*deployed)(?!.*[->OK])(?!.*complete.*)(?!.*There are no.*)(?!.*disabled.*).*TR\d{4}.*', line):
                        tr.append(match.group(0))

if errors == []:
    errors.append("No errors found.")
[...]
sendmail():
    "Errors:\n\n%s\n" % "\n".join(map(str, errors)) +
    "\Faulty:\n\n%s\n" % "\n".join(map(str, tr)) +
    "\Warnings:\n\n%s\n" % "\n".join(map(str, warnings))
sendmail()
```

The output of this is:

```
Errors:
No errors found.
Faulty:
<the entire line containing the matched regex>
Warnings:
No errors found.
```

What I would like to do is to add the full path of the log file in which an error is found, so it would instead read as:

```
Errors:
No errors found.
Faulty:
<the entire line containing the matched regex>
Error found in file: E:\Data\Production\qwer\asdf\zxcv.log
Warnings:
No warnings found.
```

I assume I need to append the fullpath variable somehow, but I am at a loss on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need.

```
for match in re.finditer(r'.*' + daysdate + '.*(?!.*deployed)(?!.*[->OK])(?!.*complete.*)(?!.*There are no.*)(?!.*disabled.*).*TR\d{4}.*', line):
    tr.append(match.group(0) + "\n{0}".format(fullpath))
```